# How can I map a model to a specific controller in CodeIgniter-Simpletest unit test framework?

Tags: codeigniter, phpunit, simpletest

I am using codeigniter framework and I am using simpletest framework for unit testing my models.

Each model have their own controller.

Most of the url(s) that I use (for webservice response) for each model is mentioned in their own controller Constructor.

When i run simpletest for each model, it takes all url from default controller which is set in routes.php.

For example :

Lets consider there are two controllers : controller1  & controller2
And there are two models : model1 & model2

controller1 is mapped to model1  &  controller2 is mapped to model2

In routes.php, I have

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller1";
```

If I unit test my model2, I need my model2 to be mapped to controller2 however it gets
mapped to controller1 itself.

Is there a way to dynamically change the default controller for each model?Or is there a way in simpletest framework to specify it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you lost me. You load models from within controllers. What do you mean you are mapping a model to a controller? In controller1 you need to have $this->load->model('model1'); and same in controller2 with model2. Then each controller can only use that one model.

Comment: sorry to use the word mapping.I meant that particular controller is for that particular model and hence used the word mapping. Ya , i have loaded the model in the way we used to do. But still when we use simpletest it takes url from default controller that is defined in routes.php

Comment: Hmm, still trying to fully understand. It sounds like you are having an issue with trying to access the correct controller from a URL. You say that the default controller is "controller1" so the root URL goes to that (http://www.yourdomain.com/). Now you are trying to run simpletest on controller2. What URL are you using to try and access controller2? Can you not use http://www.yourdomain.com/controller2 ?

Comment: By 'url' i didnt mean the domain url.These are the webservice urls that are used to fetch the data in the form of xml.Each controllers have definite set of urls to fetch thier respective data.I hope now you got my question clear.And thank you so much for spending your time.